# Gatsby - Styled components delayed loading

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

Here is a link to a gatsby [webpage](https://adoring-visvesvaraya-fff191.netlify.com/) which is working well on localhost. However, when the page is deployed on, for example, Netlify, the CSS style is applied after some time so the user can see the lag which doesn't look very good.

[Here](https://streamable.com/p1inc) is recorded the problem. [Here](https://github.com/marekmika/gatsby-landing-page-problem) is a repository. Basically webpage is composed of [section-one.tsx](https://github.com/marekmika/gatsby-landing-page-problem/blob/master/src/components/sections/section-one.tsx).

Expected result is that the webpage content should be shown only when everything is ready. Is there a solution with a loader spin or something like that?

I found some similar threads but nothing was helpful for my case.

Comment: The video and the website do not show what you describe. Instead what is shown is precisely the type of progressive loading that is explicitly encouraged by the Google Speed project and by best practices. The benefit of using Gatsby and Gatsby Image is that you get this mostly out of the box.

Comment: I agree with @coreyward in his comment. What you describe as the expected result are not the best practices that Gatsby follows. Here is a blog post (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-10-03-gatsby-perf/) from the Gatsby team that illustrates how they aim to create performant sites.